# "as little as possible" vs. "as least as possible"

Tags: phrase-usage, adverbs, as, superlatives

I am not able to understand when "as little as possible" or "as least as possible" should be used.

For example, I cannot understand which is the more appropriate form in the following example

> 1. Energy for transportation from heat source to evaporator needs to be as least as possible
> 2. energy for transportation from heat source to evaporator needs to be as little as possible

Comment: Instead of "as least as possible", people say "the least possible".

Comment: **Equative** constructions use _as...as_. **Superlative** constructions use _least_. One or the other, not both.

Answer (score 3):

First off, `as little as possible` is the only option that I have ever read or used. I believe the other example you listed is grammatically correct, but it really isn't used.

Second, your example sentence should read:

`Energy for transportation from heat source to evaporator needs to be used as little as possible.`

The term means basically, while you may need to use some energy you should try to use the least amount that you can function with.

Other uses would be:

`The hotel did as little as possible to make me comfortable! They only gave me one towel, and there wasn't even a coffee machine`